# Set textField end constraint to parentView center X Using constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 textfields. I want to set textField 1 end & textField 2 start to parent view center X. My approach is equal width text fields with layout margins.How I do this with android constraintlayout.

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the use of **Guideline**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ref :: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline

A Guideline can be either horizontal or vertical:

- Vertical Guidelines have a width of zero and the height of their ConstraintLayout parent
- Horizontal Guidelines have a height of zero and the width of their ConstraintLayout parent

Positioning a Guideline is possible in three different ways:

- specifying a fixed distance from the left or the top of a layout (`layout_constraintGuide_begin`)
- specifying a fixed distance from the right or the bottom of a layout (`layout_constraintGuide_end`)
- specifying a percentage of the width or the height of a layout
  (`layout_constraintGuide_percent`)

Ref :: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

- `android:layout_margin` Specifies extra space on the left, top, right and bottom sides of this view.
- `android:layout_marginBottom`    Specifies extra space on the bottom side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginEnd`   Specifies extra space on the end side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginHorizontal`    Specifies extra space on the left and right sides of this view.
- `android:layout_marginLeft`  Specifies extra space on the left side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginRight` Specifies extra space on the right side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginStart` Specifies extra space on the start side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginTop`   Specifies extra space on the top side of this view.
- `android:layout_marginVertical`  Specifies extra space on the top and bottom sides of this view.

Comment: But how I add layout margins?

Comment: `android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"` and `android:layout_marginStart="8dp"`

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha or use `android:layout_marginRight="8dp"` and `android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
        />
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As per your image layout you need to use guideline. Guidelines can be oriented either horizontally or vertically.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextField1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextField2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```